# how to fix sizes of figures in facet_wrap() or multiplot() in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-columns, facet-wrap

I want to plot multiple figures with several panels.

The data structure I have,

```
quality organism      component   group value   se
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C16.1     MUFA  0.022336602 0.001715501
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C16.2n4   PUFA  0           0
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C16.3n4   PUFA  0.001106097 0.00096191
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.0     SFA   0.022975838 0.01324553
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.1n9t  MUFA  0.01571751  0.02271655
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.1n9c  MUFA  0.040262837 0.02746583
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.1n7   MUFA  0.080077945 0.01098649
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.2n6t  PUFA  0.005644246 0.00265683
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.2n6c  PUFA  0.098402341 0.03755471
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.3n6   PUFA  0.013530465 0.002457633
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C18.3n3   PUFA  0.262319627 0.03994807
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.0     SFA   0           0
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.1n9c  MUFA  0.000171337 0.000296765
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.2n6c  PUFA  0.000750626 0.000302127
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.3n6   HUFA  0.000139456 0.000241546
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.4n6c  HUFA  0.009450224 0.000734239
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.3n3   HUFA  0.00504895  0.006997548
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C22.0     SFA   0           0
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C20.5n3c  HUFA  0.120287457 0.01227192
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C22.1n9c  MUFA  0.007986444 0.008414274
Rho(-)  Phytoplankton   C24.0     SFA   0.00121246  0.000926446
```

I tried two methods to make the plot,

**Method 1**(plot quality separately, and use multiplot())

```
P.polyp.artem <-
   ggplot(polyp.artem2SE, aes(x=component, y=value*100, fill=group))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity", colour='grey')+
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(value-se)*100, ymax=(value+se)*100),
            width=0.3)+
   scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))+
   scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,40))+
   scale_fill_brewer(palette="Reds")+
   labs(x='',
        y='',
        title='  Polyp(Art)')+
   mytheme+
   theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,0,0), "lines"),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, b = -20), size=12),
        panel.border=element_blank())

multiplot(P.polyp.aca1, P.aca1, P.rho1,
          P.polyp.aca2, P.aca2, P.rho2,
          P.polyp.artem,P.artem,
          cols=3)
... ...
```

The plot likes,
 [image]

My question for this fig is, **1)** how can I adjust the figure area of those three with x axis text as the same size with others; **2)** how can I extract legend from figures and put it right down position?

**Method 2** (plot with facet_wrap() in ggplot2)

```
ggplot(data=foodquality.fa, aes(x=component, y=value*100, fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_dodge()) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(value-se)*100, ymax=(value+se)*100),
                position = position_dodge(), width=0.3)+

  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,40))+

  facet_wrap(organism~quality) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens")+

  labs(x='',
       y='% Total FA'
       )+

  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0)+

  mytheme+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.7,0.15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust=1, size=10),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        strip.text=element_blank(),
        strip.background=element_rect(colour="white", 
                                      fill="white"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

The plot like,
 [image]
For this fig, I would like to **1)** keep the vertical lines in each panel; **2)**If I can do the right two panel with a different fill color, would be perfect.

Any approved of these two figures, I would be very appreciated it!!!
Thank you.

Comment: A simple and flexible solution is to create separately your 8 plots and then to arrange them in a single plot. See `grid.arrange` in the `gridExtra` package or see ` ggarrange` in `ggpubr`: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Just to add to Marco Sandri's comment, a viable solution is also [plot_grid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/0.8.0/topics/plot_grid) in pacakge cowplot.

Comment: @MarcoSandri,@missuse, thank you very much for your comments. I will try your suggestions.